# Excel formula concat text in excel without zero values

Tags: excel, excel-formula, concatenation, formula

I am new to excel formulas.
How to skip the zeros and the show result in image format with the yellow colour columns in the excel formula?

[image]

Comment: Which version of Excel do you have?

Comment: @rory it is Microsoft 365

Comment: You would make life easier for all if you posted data we could copy instead of a picture that we cannot. Boring and time consuming to type in your data...

Answer (score 1):

If the results are not always in ascending order (if they are @Solar Mike has already solved it for you with MAX) then perhaps:

```
=A2&" "&LOOKUP(2,1/(B2:D2<>0),B2:D2)
```

Comment: Thanks @rory. It is working as excepted. Thanks you so much.

Comment: Does this only work with certain versions of excel?

Comment: @DavePile No it should work with any version.

Answer (score 1):

As per your sample data it seems simple below formula should work.

```
=A2&" "&MAX(B2:D2)
```

Or can try-

```
=A2 & " " & XLOOKUP(1000,B2:D2,B2:D2,,-1,-1)
```

and if you want actually non zero right cell data (including text data) then use `FILTERXML()` like-

```
=A2& " " & FILTERXML("<t><s>"&TEXTJOIN("</s><s>",TRUE,FILTER(B2:D2,B2:D2>0))&"</s></t>","//s[last()]")
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your results however, then this:

[image]
Something like:

=if(A2>0,A2&" ","")&if(B2>0,B2&" ","")&if(C2>0,C2&" ","")&if(D2>0,D2&" ","")

will work.
Probably could be made shorter... And should work with all versions of Excel.

Ba

Comment: Hi @solar Mike, The result is different. `Result
1 2 
1 2 3 
1 2 3 4 
1 2 3 4 
1 2 
1 2 3 
1 2 3 4 
1 2 
1 2 3 
1 2 3 4 
`

Comment: @PradeepRaoM Hi to you too.

Comment: @PradeepRaoM check out my version 2. Which I had updated prior to your comment.

Answer (score 0):

In one single Cell:

```
Cell E2 =TEXTJOIN(" ";TRUE;IF(A2:D2=0;"";A2:D2))
```

Or if you are looking from min max only:

```
cell E2 = MIN(a2:d2)&" "&MAX(a2:d2)
```